Understanding basic options arbitrage in Hull
I’m reading Hull’s book, Options, Futures and Other Derivatives.
In Chapter 11 he discusses put-call parity and the arbitrage opportunities that can result from its violation.
I’m having a basic issue, which is it seems he is shorting stock without paying interest. Here’s a concrete example from his section 11.3 concerning a European call:
Suppose that $S_0$ = \$20, K = \$18, r = 10% per annum, and T = 1 year. In this case,
$$S_0 - Ke^{-rT}= 20 - 18e^{-0.1}= 3.71$$
or \$3.71. Consider the situation where the European call price is \$3.00, which is less
than the theoretical minimum of \$3.71. An arbitrageur can short the stock and buy the call to provide a cash inflow of \$20.00 - \$3.00 = \$17.00. If invested for 1 year at 10% per annum, the \$17.00 grows to $17e^{0.1*1} = \\\$18.79$. At the end of the year, the option expires. If the stock price is greater than \$18.00, the arbitrageur exercises the option paying \$18.00 for the stock and uses the stock to close out the short position. This leads to a profit of
\$18.79 - \$18.00 = \$0.79
====
I don’t understand how in this scenario the arbitrager doesn’t need to pay interest over the 1 year on the $20 he borrowed to short the stock.

Ermm...why would you borrow to short the stock ? Or do you mean haircut /eq repo or something else?

According to investopedia: ‘To open a short position, a trader must have a margin account and pay interest on the value of the borrowed shares while the position is open.’

Hmm, I'd just borrow the share, sell it, get cash, lend that cash to the person I borrowed it from and because cash is king tell them to also pay me some interest..same thing as a rev repo of a bond (assuming no h/c).

If you bought one share at $20 on margin, sold it and bought the call, I don’t see how your $17 cash would mean you wouldn’t need to pay interest in your margin account.

When you short a share you don't buy it

Generally, investopedia is so full of errors that it's almost useless.

Or it is so vague that the reason you have arrived at the website is impossible to determine through the non-specificity of its descriptions. I always avoid investopedia when it appears in a google search.

The example assumes cost of carry / dividend yields are zero so you can ignore them. You can make the example a lot more complicated and include them if you want.

Yeah I guess my use of word ‘interest’ confused a lot of people. Apparently the better term is ‘borrow rate,’ and it can be lower or higher than the Fed Funds rate depending on the stock. Brokers do charge a borrow rate, although if this example is written from the perspective of a broker itself, the broker would presumably not have to pay a borrow rate because the broker could borrow stock from its retail clients without paying them a fee. Thanks for the comments.
